Is there a way to align images to the top in a table?
I don't know if this question was answered before.
Is there a way to align images to the top in a table:



Picture one
Picture two










I don't think you can. The worst that might work is creating a new image with same size of the left image and then place your right image in it at the position you need and then upload that new image.

How difficult is to set "vertical-align: top;" as default in the cell instead middle?

Images of buildings is an interesting choice for top alignment.

It is difficult because on SE only a limited set of HTML attributes is allowed and  Common Mark doesn't have support for it as far as I'm aware.

I understand. Since I saw that horizontal alignment is possible, I thought it would be a good option to also have the vertical one.

@ElementsInSpace I guess a solution would be equally applicable to bottom-align images :)

Unfortunately you can't.
The allowed HTML elements and their attributes is limited as described in What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites? and there is no option to control vertical alignment.
The markdown flavor used by Stack Overflow, Common Mark, doesn't offer support for tables at all, so Stack Exchange uses an own implementation: New Feature: Table Support and that does explain the horizontal alignment option but lacks any vertical alignment capability.
The actual CSS rule vertical-alignment: middle on the <td> element comes straight from the Stack Design System. The only CSS rule comes from the class s-table and that defines the value of the var --_ta-td-va as middle. That is the default value and that var gets applied here. There is no markdown or markup you can apply to overrule these values.
If you want to align images, it is on you to make them the same height. That is a workaround at best.
I couldn't find a feature request for adding support on vertical alignment. If no such request exist yet and you feel strongly about this capability that might benefit more contributors across the network, consider posting a proper feature request.
